# 'current_page?' not working on application layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got a rails application that shows a list of shops. I'm trying to get it to hide the header when the user is on the shops page (/merchant/:username).

In my application.html.erb

```
<% if current_page?(menu_path) %>
<% else %>
<%= render "shared/header" %>
<% end %>
```

My Routes:

```
match '/merchant/:username', to: 'merchants#show', via: 'get', as: 'menu'
```

I also tried:

```
<% if current_page?(:controller => 'merchants', :action => 'show') %>
```

Both these work in the /merchant/:username page and hide the header like expected but on the homepage I'm getting errors:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"merchants"}
```

and

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"merchants"}, missing required keys: [:username]
```

Comment: what is current_page return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your route needs a param (`:username`), which doesn't exist when you are on the homepage.

You can try this:

```rb
<% if controller.controller_name == 'merchants' &&
      controller.action_name == 'show' %>
<% else %>
<%= render "shared/header" %>
<% end %>
```

**EDIT:** added `controller_name`

Maybe you could use `content_for` o partials in merchants' views.

Comment: Thanks this works, but if I have another controller that also has an action called 'show' then I assume this will also hide the header for that route, is the a way to specify it for only the merchant controller?

Comment: Sure, you can use `controller_name`. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missing username key in current_page helper.

```rb
current_page?(controller: 'merchants', action: 'show', username: 'example')
```